# Can a for loop work with random number?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

This is my first attempt at printing out a set of 50 random ints of the range -20 to 20.

```
int set1 = (int)(Math.random() * (40) + (-20) );
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for ( int set2 =1; set2 < 20 ; set2 = set1 )
    System.out.print(set2);
```

Can anyone help my understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?

Comment: Seems like it would generate an infinite loop.

Comment: @emschorsch -- Nah, the computer would fail sooner or later.

Comment: infinite loop , I confuse how i can put random number in for loop

Comment: This is code is wrong! You are only creating your random number once

Comment: You don't have a very good understanding of what `for` loop is, or how it works.  Go back and read your textbook again, and study the examples more closely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way to go:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    int random = (int)(Math.random() * (40) + (-20) );
    System.out.print(random);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A for loop should be made up of a declaration, a condition, and an incrementation. If you had the last part as `set2 += set1` then it would work...

You would want to run the for loop 50 times using

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i ++){
    //generate random number here, print here
    int random = (int)(Math.random() * (40) + (-20) );
    System.out.print(random);
}
```

And in every loop you generate a new number...

Comment: It shouldn't be.. do people not get the idea of generating 50 random numbers? Did anyone read the question -.-

Comment: So my answer which corrected him and explains it gets 2 voted down, then another persons posted after with pretty much the same thing with hardly any explaining gets voted up -.- what is with this.